# Is the matrix multiplication exponent $\omega$ independent from the choice of the base field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, algebraic-complexity

The matrix multiplication exponent, usually denoted by $\omega_{F}$, is the smallest real number for which any two $n\times n$ matrices over a field $F$ can be multiplied together using  ${\displaystyle n^{\omega +o(1)}}$ field operations. My question is if $\omega_{F}$ is always a constant independent of the choice of $F$.

Comment: I believe that the current answer to this question is "we don't know". There's no obvious reason why $\omega_F$ would have to be field-independent, but for all we know at this point it could be the case that $\omega_F = 2$ for every field.